# How to enforce wicket to validate disabled fields on the page right before onsubmit call

Tags: wicket

if we use setEnabled(false) say on text input type it disables and not take part in form validation so how can i enoforce this right before onsubmit

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule browsers do not submit the value of disabled fields at all. (As [mandated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) by the HTML standard)

It's important to see that because of the browser sending no data, the problem is framework-neutral. The solution is also independent of your framework:

1. Double-fielding: each text field that you intend to disable should have a "shadow" hidden field where its value is copied.
2. In the Javascript function that does the submitting you can re-enable the fields for the time of submit only. I haven't tried this option yet so I'm not sure if this is a good idea or indeed if it works (it should though).

A separate, Wicket-specific issue is that even if the browser submits the values, any Wicket component which has `setEnabled(false)` called will refuse to process them. So you'll have to extend double-fielding into your Wicket component structure as well, which won't look very nice.

So it's doable but you should know that users will *not* expect disabled fields to be submitted and you're likely to cause confusion by changing the standard behaviour of form inputs. You might want to think about redesigning your UI as an alternative option.

Answer (score 1):

If the component is disabled it won't have any input to be validated. I'll assume from now on that you want to execute a `FormValidator` which involves some other components' user input and this disabled `TextField`'s model object.

Unless you return the disabled `TextField` in [`FormValidator.getDependentFormComponents()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/validation/IFormValidator.html#getDependentFormComponents%28%29), the `FormValidator` will continue to execute. Take into account that [`FormComponent.getConvertedInput()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html#getConvertedInput%28%29) won't return anything, because there's no input. You can get the Modelobject instead by using [`FormComponent.getValue()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html#getValue%28%29).